# Как сделать чтобы max() возвращал самое большое число, а не самое большое первое число (букву)

Tags: python

```
numbers = ("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
print(numbers)
a = numbers.split()
print(a)
print (max(a))
print (min (int(a)))
```

Выведет:

> 6 и -214

А должен вывести:

> 542

Comment: `max(map(int, a))`

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло

Comment: В Вашем коде возвращаются не числа, а строки. Подумайте.

Comment: Знаю, не знаю как сделать чтобы возвращало числа, знаний не хватает, какая то map() функция, сейчас прочту про неё

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При работе со строками используется [лексикографическое сравнение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA):

```
In [19]: "9" > "1000"
Out[19]: True
```

поэтому сначала преобразуйте элементы в числа - для этого можно воспользоваться функцией [map(int, iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) ("функциональный стиль"):

```
max_ = max(map(int, a))
```

или генератором:

```
max_ = max(int(x) for x in a)
```

---

[@hoefling](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1012105/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-max-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5#comment1717725_1012108) посоветовал лучший вариант если в качестве результата нужна строка `"542"`, а не число:

```
In [2]: max(a, key=int)
Out[2]: '542'
```

Comment: Можно еще `max(a, key=int)`, если конвертация текста в числа не требуется.

Comment: @hoefling, отличная идея! Дополню ответ когда буду за компьютером